# custom material style input with label not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms, css

I have created a material design style input form with label, here is a [JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/uk104m5p/4/) It seems to be working fine, but it only works when I add `required` in input tag, if I remove `required` from input it stopped working, not sure why, can somebody please look in to it?

thanks in advance.

```css
.ttl{
  font-size:16px;
  margin:10px 0;
}
.form-row:nth-child(1){
  margin-top:50px;
}
.form-row {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.form-group input {
  height: 2.5rem;
}
.form-group .control-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.25rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding-left: 0.125rem;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #696969;
  font-size: 1.750rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.28s ease;
  transition: all 0.28s ease;
  font-family: 'Montserrat-Regular';
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.form-group .bar {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 0.0625rem solid #999;
  display: block;
}
.form-group .bar::before {
  content: '';
  height: 0.125rem;
  width: 0;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -0.0625rem;
  position: absolute;
  background: #40b8f1;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.28s ease, width 0.28s ease;
  transition: left 0.28s ease, width 0.28s ease;
  z-index: 2;
}
.form-group input, .form-group textarea {
  display: block;
  background: none;
  padding: 0.125rem 0.125rem 0.0625rem;
  font-size: 1.750rem;
  border-width: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  line-height: 2;
  width: 100%;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.28s ease;
  transition: all 0.28s ease;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.form-group select ~ .control-label, .form-group input:focus ~ .control-label, .form-group input:valid ~ .control-label, .form-group input.form-file ~ .control-label, .form-group input.has-value ~ .control-label, .form-group textarea:focus ~ .control-label, .form-group textarea:valid ~ .control-label, .form-group textarea.form-file ~ .control-label, .form-group textarea.has-value ~ .control-label {
  font-size: 1.750rem;
  color: gray;
  top: -2.750rem;
  left: 0;
}
.form-group select:focus ~ .bar::before, .form-group input:focus ~ .bar::before, .form-group textarea:focus ~ .bar::before {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<p class="ttl">Without required it doesn't work</p>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="student">
    <label for="input" class="control-label">Label Title here</label>
    <i class="bar"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<p class="ttl">With required it works</p>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input required type="text" name="student">
    <label for="input" class="control-label">Label Title here</label>
    <i class="bar"></i> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: valid input needs the field to be required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove  `.form-group input:valid ~ .control-label` from the style of input focused

Change to This

```
 .form-group select ~ .control-label, .form-group input:focus ~   .control-label, .form-group input.form-file ~ .control-label, .form-group input.has-value ~ .control-label, .form-group textarea:focus ~ .control-label, .form-group textarea:valid ~ .control-label, .form-group textarea.form-file ~ .control-label, .form-group textarea.has-value ~       .control-label {
 font-size: 1.750rem;
 color: gray;
 top: -2.750rem;
 left: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fy577w6b/3/

Or add styles for the control label when input is invalid.

Comment: thanks its working fine, I just didn't noticed this valid section

Comment: after applying the changes, there was a new problem, that is when value entered the label was overlapping the input value and to fix this I had to write 2 lines of jquery, that is $(".form-group > input").focusout(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {    
    $(this).next("label").addClass("frm-top");
   }else{
    $(this).next("label").removeClass("frm-top");
  }
 });

Answer (score 0):

Just add below Css.

```
 .form-group , .form-group input:valid ~ .control-label{top:0;}
 .form-group input:focus ~ .control-label{top: -2.750rem;}
```

```css
.ttl{font-size:16px; margin:10px 0;}
.form-row:nth-child(1){margin-top:50px;}
.form-row {
margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
float: left;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}
.form-group input {
height: 2.5rem;
}
.form-group .control-label {
position: absolute;
top: 0.25rem;
pointer-events: none;
padding-left: 0.125rem;
z-index: 1;
color: #696969;
font-size: 1.750rem;
font-weight: normal;
-webkit-transition: all 0.28s ease;
transition: all 0.28s ease;
font-family: 'Montserrat-Regular';
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
.form-group .bar {
position: relative;
border-bottom: 0.0625rem solid #999;
display: block;
}
.form-group .bar::before {
content: '';
height: 0.125rem;
width: 0;
left: 50%;
bottom: -0.0625rem;
position: absolute;
background: #40b8f1;
-webkit-transition: left 0.28s ease, width 0.28s ease;
transition: left 0.28s ease, width 0.28s ease;
z-index: 2;
}
.form-group input, .form-group textarea {
display: block;
background: none;
padding: 0.125rem 0.125rem 0.0625rem;
font-size: 1.750rem;
border-width: 0;
border-color: transparent;
line-height: 2;
width: 100%;
color: transparent;
-webkit-transition: all 0.28s ease;
transition: all 0.28s ease;
box-shadow: none;
text-align: center;
}
 .form-group select ~ .control-label, .form-group input:focus ~ .control-label, .form-group input:valid ~ .control-label, .form-group input.form-file ~ .control-label, .form-group input.has-value ~ .control-label, .form-group textarea:focus ~ .control-label, .form-group textarea:valid ~ .control-label, .form-group textarea.form-file ~ .control-label, .form-group textarea.has-value ~ .control-label {
 font-size: 1.750rem;
 color: gray;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
.form-group select:focus ~ .bar::before, .form-group input:focus ~ .bar::before, .form-group textarea:focus ~ .bar::before {
width: 100%;
left: 0;
}
   .form-group , .form-group input:valid ~ .control-label{top:0;}
   .form-group input:focus ~ .control-label{top: -2.750rem;}
```

```html
<p class="ttl">Without required it doesn't work</p>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="student" required>
<label for="input" class="control-label">Label Title here</label>
<i class="bar"></i> </div>
</div>
<p class="ttl">With required it works</p>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group">
<input required type="text" name="student" required>
<label for="input" class="control-label">Label Title here</label>
<i class="bar"></i> </div>
</div>
```